# Inter communication between microservice in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, microservices

I am developing microservices using SpringBoot and using Kubernetes for deployment. For that I have two services Order and Customer.
Then Order service calls the Customer service to get some data on http protocol. It call Kubernetes service. I tried both name of Customer service and ip as well but during this communication it throw time out exception.

Following is piece of code.

Customer Service :
[image]

[image]

I tried to use call both using IP address and service name as well, something like below code.
but it does not work.

[image]

It throws following error. In screen shot I attach with name but It gives me same error with IP address as well.
Its Minikube single node cluster.

What wrong I am doing here?
[image]

Comment: One possible issue is that dns of kubernetes is not working. Also in order to provide you answer give some code to reproduce it and also if possible yaml.

Comment: First make sure your pods are running for customer-service. Check the logs of one pod. Your snippet shows you are trying `http://ingress-serviceingress/customers/1` we might want to check if your URL is configured correctly in `order-service`.  just `http://customer-service:8080/customers/1` should work. Otherwise try showing you yamls here

Answer (score 0):

- Please use below link to troubleshoot Kubernetes Services

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/

- Please use below commands to check if you can curl to Kubernetes Service customer-service on Port 8080 from any pod inside the same namespace

```
kubectl run -it --rm=true --restart=Never curl --image=radial/busyboxplus -- curl http://customer-service:8080

kubectl run -it --rm=true --restart=Never curl --image=radial/busyboxplus -- curl http://10.104.255.198:8080
```

- Also order-service Pods should call Customer Service Pods using customer-service and not using Ingress. Ingress is for sending requests to Customer Service Pods from outside the kubernetes cluster

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following steps to check:
1.Use the telnet command to check access to the POD mapping port;
2.Check whether your Service rules are configured correctly, here you can debug by creating a Node port type;
3.Check iptables or ipvs in your underlying communication forwarding rules;